# Use of 'the' after 'both'

Tags: articles

Is using 'the' after 'both' in the sentence example correct?

> 'He is both **the** troublemaker and worth the trouble'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, Tony! Yes, your sentence is correct. An alternative sentence would be "He is the troublemaker but worth the trouble." Your example focuses on both characteristics whereas this alternative shows one characteristic in opposition to the other. Yours is absolutely correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Edward for the clarification. Can you also tell me why would it be wrong to remove 'the' from the sentence? i.e. 'He is both troublemaker and worth the trouble.'

Comment: I see @djclayworth answered this question.

Comment: @Tony It would *not* be wrong to remove *the*. The most idiomatic way of doing so would involve a slight rephrasing: *He is both troublemaker and worthy of trouble*. But even just removing it without additional rephrasing would still be grammatical (if not entirely natural).

Answer (score 0):

The word "the" is required because it would be required in the case where you were talking about only the first thing.

> CORRECT: He is the troublemaker.
>
> INCORRECT: He is troublemaker.
>
> CORRECT: He is worth the trouble

So to convert "He is A" and "He is B" to a combined statement you insert "both" and "and", leaving "He is both A and B". In your case:

> He is **both** the troublemaker **and** worth the trouble

Comment: Thanks DJClayworth. Can I also use 'He is a troublemaker and worth the trouble'?

Comment: Yes you can use that.